# Connect Webserver to swift to adjust volume

Tags: php, swift, webserver

I want to connect from a webserver to my ios app. I want that if you are on the website that you can control your phone. Just small things like adjust volume. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: nothing. I just want to know is this possible or not ..

Comment: everything is possible.